# Authorization error while using JWT in gRPC ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, asp.net-identity, grpc

I used gRPC to try to make JWT authorization, but when I try to authorization, I get an error on the client:

```
Grpc.Core.RpcException: "Status(StatusCode="Unimplemented", Detail="Bad gRPC response. HTTP status code: 404")"
```

I can’t figure out what this is about.

**My gRPC Server:**

*Startup.cs:*

```
using AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo;
using GrpcServiceTiEventsy.MongoDB.Identity;
using GrpcServiceTiEventsy.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Text;

namespace GrpcServiceTiEventsy
{
    public class Startup
    {

        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _securityKey;
        public static MongoClient MongoDbClient { get; private set; }
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }


        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Token:SecretKey"]));
            MongoDbClient = new MongoClient(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDB"));
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();

            services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient, MongoClient>(sp => MongoDbClient);

            services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<DatabaseAccount, DatabaseRole>(identity =>
                {
                    identity.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                    identity.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    identity.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    identity.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    identity.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                },
                mongo =>
                    mongo.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDB") + "/TiEventsyIdentity"
                );

            services.AddAuthorization(options =>
            {
                options.AddPolicy(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme, policy =>
                {
                    policy.AddAuthenticationSchemes(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
                    policy.RequireClaim(ClaimTypes.Name);
                });
            });

            services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme).AddJwtBearer(
                opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateActor = false,

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Token:Issuer"],

                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Token:Audience"],

                        ValidateLifetime = true,

                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = _securityKey
                    };
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<LoginService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<RefreshedTokenService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<RegistrationService>();
            });
        }
    }

}
```

*TokensGenerator.cs:*

```
using System;
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
using System.Security.Claims;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Core;
using GrpcServiceTiEventsy.MongoDB.Identity;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using MongoDB.Driver;

namespace GrpcServiceTiEventsy.Models.Tokens
{
    public static class TokensGenerator
    {

        private static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SecurityKey 
            = new (Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Startup.Configuration["Token:SecretKey"]));

        public static async Task<(string, string)> CreateTokens(DatabaseAccount account) =>
            (CreateJwt(account), await CreateRefreshToken(account));
        

        public static async Task<(string, string)>  CreateTokens(DatabaseAccount account, string jwtToken, string refreshToken)
        {
            if (ValidateJwtToken(jwtToken) && ValidateRefreshToken(account, refreshToken))
                return (CreateJwt(account), await CreateRefreshToken(account));

            throw new RpcException(Status.DefaultSuccess,"Tokens are not real");
        }

        private static bool ValidateRefreshToken(DatabaseAccount account, string token)
            => account.RefreshToken == token;

        private static bool ValidateJwtToken(string token)
        {
            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

            try
            {
                tokenHandler.ValidateToken(token, new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateActor = false,

                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = Startup.Configuration["Token:Issuer"],

                    ValidateAudience = true,
                    ValidAudience = Startup.Configuration["Token:Audience"],

                    ValidateLifetime = false,

                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                    IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKey

                }, out var validatedToken);

                return true;
            }
            catch
            {
                return false;
            }
            
        }

        private static string CreateJwt(DatabaseAccount account)
        {
            var claims = new[] { new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, account.UserName) };

            var credentials = new SigningCredentials(SecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);

            var expiresDays = Convert.ToInt32(Startup.Configuration["Token:LifetimeDay"]);

            var tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();
            
            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                Startup.Configuration["Token:Issuer"],
                Startup.Configuration["Token:Audience"], 
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.Now.AddDays(expiresDays), 
                signingCredentials: credentials);

            return tokenHandler.WriteToken(token);
        }

        private static async Task<string> CreateRefreshToken(DatabaseAccount account)
        {
            var randomNumber = new byte[32];

            using (var rng = RandomNumberGenerator.Create())
                rng.GetBytes(randomNumber);
            var token = Convert.ToBase64String(randomNumber);

            var identityDb = Startup.MongoDbClient.GetDatabase("TiEventsyIdentity");
            var accountsCollection = identityDb.GetCollection<DatabaseAccount>("Users");

            var user = await accountsCollection.Find(ac => ac.Id == account.Id).FirstOrDefaultAsync();

            if (user != null)
            {
                var filter = Builders<DatabaseAccount>.Filter.Eq(s => s.Id, account.Id);
                var update = Builders<DatabaseAccount>.Update.Set(s => s.RefreshToken, token);

                await accountsCollection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, update);
            }
            else throw new RpcException(Status.DefaultSuccess,"No such user exists");
            

            return token;
        }
    }
}
```

*GreeterService.cs:*

```
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Core;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace GrpcServiceTiEventsy.Services
{
    public class GreeterService : Greeter.GreeterBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<GreeterService> _logger;
        public GreeterService(ILogger<GreeterService> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [Authorize]
        public override Task<HelloReply> SayHello(HelloRequest request, ServerCallContext context)
        {
            return Task.FromResult(new HelloReply
            {
                Message = "Hello " + request.Name
            });
        }
    }
}
```

**My Client:**

*Program.cs:*

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Grpc.Core;
using Grpc.Net.Client;
using GrpcServiceTiEventsy;


Console.WriteLine("Param...");

var channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001");

Console.WriteLine("Log...");

var l = new Login.LoginClient(channel);
var tokens = await l.LogAsync(new LoginRequest { Email = "igorka@gmail.com", Password = "pas@jKH$KJJT34592345" });
Console.WriteLine($"\n Access: {tokens.AccessToken}" +
                  $"\n Refresh: {tokens.RefreshToken}" +
                   "\n");

var credentials = CallCredentials.FromInterceptor((context, metadata) =>
{
    metadata.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {tokens.AccessToken}");
    return Task.CompletedTask;
});

channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress("https://localhost:5001", new GrpcChannelOptions
{
    Credentials = ChannelCredentials.Create(new SslCredentials(), credentials)
});

Console.WriteLine("Test Auth...");
var te = new Greeter.GreeterClient(channel);
var outD = await te.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "igorka@gmail.com" });
Console.WriteLine("Out: " +outD);
```

Error inferred here `var outD = await te.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "igorka@gmail.com" });`

*If you wait for additional information, you will denigrate it in comments.*

Comment: I don't see the `SayHelloAsync` defined on your server service. But somehow it's generated for the client class. That's strange. Looks like you need to reupdate your client classes (by updating some service contract file or reference) and use just defined methods on your service.

Comment: @KingKing gRPC looks like an automatically gingered Async methods. And if you remove `[Authorize]`, everything works.

Comment: so it's the issue of authorization, but strangely that the response status code is `404`, it should be `401` or `403` depending on the authentication state of your request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a long debug and reading articles, I made the right Startup.cs.

*Here is the working Startup.cs:*

```
using AspNetCore.Identity.Mongo;
using GrpcServiceTiEventsy.MongoDB.Identity;
using GrpcServiceTiEventsy.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using MongoDB.Driver;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;

namespace GrpcServiceTiEventsy
{
    public class Startup
    {

        private readonly SymmetricSecurityKey _securityKey;
        public static MongoClient MongoDbClient { get; private set; }
        public static IConfiguration Configuration { get; private set; }


        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _securityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(Configuration["Token:SecretKey"]));
            MongoDbClient = new MongoClient(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDB"));
        }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddGrpc();

            services.AddSingleton<IMongoClient, MongoClient>(sp => MongoDbClient);

            services.AddIdentityMongoDbProvider<DatabaseAccount, DatabaseRole>(identity =>
                {
                    identity.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
                    identity.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
                    identity.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
                    identity.Password.RequireUppercase = false;
                    identity.Password.RequireDigit = false;
                },
                mongo =>
                    mongo.ConnectionString = Configuration.GetConnectionString("MongoDB") + "/TiEventsyIdentity"
                ).AddDefaultTokenProviders();


            services
                .AddAuthorization()
                .AddAuthentication(options =>
                {
                    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                })
                .AddJwtBearer(
                opt =>
                {
                    opt.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        ValidateActor = false,

                        ValidateIssuer = true,
                        ValidIssuer = Configuration["Token:Issuer"],

                        ValidateAudience = true,
                        ValidAudience = Configuration["Token:Audience"],

                        ValidateLifetime = true,


                        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = _securityKey
                    };
                });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<GreeterService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<LoginService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<RefreshedTokenService>();
                endpoints.MapGrpcService<RegistrationService>();
            });
        }
    }
}
```